# Mongo db join 2 or more collection and get row wise results

Tags: mongodb, join, collections

I have 2 tables for now, 1) material master another is 2)forcast table.
localField is Material, foreignField is MATERIAL. For a single material there are multiple entry on forcast table for each month. Now I need monthly, yearly, and current quarter sum from forcast table for a meterial.

But unable to get multiple sum(yearly, monthly).

```
db.material_master.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "monthly_forcast_table", 
                "localField" : "Material", 
                "foreignField" : "MATERIAL", 
                "as" : "forcast"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$forcast", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "forcast.EMPLOYEE CODE" : "47000006"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "$cond" : [
                        {
                            "Financial Year" : "2016-2107"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "$sum" : "$forcast.Qty"
                        }, 
                        0.0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

Data

material master

```
   { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5affd515415668486654f95e"), 
        "Focus Code" : "RMTEC0049", 
        "Material" : "100000000", 
        "Material type" : "ZROH", 
        "Brand code" : "1003", 
        "Brand name" : "Raw Material", 
        "Old Material Number" : "RMTEC0049", 
        "Material description" : "Tech Hexaconazole"
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5affd515415668486654f95f"), 
        "Focus Code" : "RMEMF0103-2", 
        "Material" : "100000001", 
        "Material type" : "ZROH", 
        "Brand code" : "1002", 
        "Brand name" : "Raw Material", 
        "Old Material Number" : "RMEMF0103-2", 
        "Material description" : "MEGASOLVE ESBO"
    }
```

and  forcust

```
   { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5affaa3e6f8be823dea6f1b0"), 
        "PRICE" : 0.0, 
        "STATE" : "GJ", 
        "REGION" : "GJ-NS", 
        "DEPOT" : "AHMEDABAD", 
        "EMPLOYEE CODE" : "47000006", 
        "EMPLOYEE NAME" : "GJ Jignesh", 
        "CATEGORY" : "NUCLEUS", 
        "BRAND" : "BRAND", 
        "PRODUCT NAME" : "BRAND ( L ) - 1 Ltr", 
        "PRODUCT CODE" : "FGMNL1041", 
        "MATERIAL" : "810000088", 
        "Financial Year" : "2015-2016", 
        "Month" : "2015-04-01", 
        "Qty" : 0.0
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5affaa3e6f8be823dea6f1b1"), 
        "PRICE" : 0.0, 
        "STATE" : "GJ", 
        "REGION" : "GJ-NS", 
        "DEPOT" : "AHMEDABAD", 
        "EMPLOYEE CODE" : "47000006", 
        "EMPLOYEE NAME" : "GJ Jignesh", 
        "CATEGORY" : "NUCLEUS", 
        "BRAND" : "BRAND", 
        "PRODUCT NAME" : "BRAND ( L ) -500 ML", 
        "PRODUCT CODE" : "FGMNL0007", 
        "MATERIAL" : "810000095", 
        "Financial Year" : "2015-2016", 
        "Month" : "2015-04-01", 
        "Qty" : 0.0
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5affaa3e6f8be823dea6f1b2"), 
        "PRICE" : 15.0, 
        "STATE" : "GJ", 
        "REGION" : "GJ-NS", 
        "DEPOT" : "AHMEDABAD", 
        "EMPLOYEE CODE" : "47000006", 
        "EMPLOYEE NAME" : "GJ Jignesh", 
        "CATEGORY" : "NUCLEUS", 
        "BRAND" : "BRAND", 
        "PRODUCT NAME" : "BRAND ( L ) -250 ML", 
        "PRODUCT CODE" : "FGMNL0008", 
        "MATERIAL" : "810000094", 
        "Financial Year" : "2015-2016", 
        "Month" : "2015-04-01", 
        "Qty" : 15.0
    }
```

Expected output:

```
Yearly sum: Qty sum for "Financial Year" : "2015-2016"
last 3 month sum : "Month" : "2015-04-01","2015-05-01","2015-06-01"
last 1 month sum : "Month" : "2015-06-01"
```

Comment: You need to actually show a small data sample and a result that you expect to achieve which can be obtained from that sample. Merely looking at the code just indicates what you attempted, but you should not presume that your desired result is just a small change. Present the problem rather than ask for a correction.

Comment: I have edited my questions, please check now

Comment: please post your sample output as well

Comment: Questions updated, plz check